# Acceleration with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a free-falling effect under the action of gravity in my browser. Basic Physics should tell you that the more the body (a div in this case) falls the faster should be its velocity.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Basically the velocity of the object should be equal to 'at' at all times. Where t = time period and a = acceleration = 9.8.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a jQuery 'physics' plugin that allows you to apply physics to elements. You can create vectors and assign velocity/gravity etc: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jphysics

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It does. But I am not really a pro at jquery and what I wanna do here is code most of it myself. Any idea where I can find either a tutorial or just a code snippet for just the acceleration part? Or can you just point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've found a couple of interesting physics tutorials/experiments people have conducted with javascript: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/blob-sallad-canvas-tag-and-javascrip/ and http://www.queness.com/post/3296/8-amazing-javascript-experiments-of-physic-and-gravity-simulation were the best two that I could find... were they more what you were looking for??

Answer (score 0):

If you are animating your effect, it would be easier for you to use the time period on the object using the time of effect in jquery.