# How to simulate dropping stones into a bucket on the web?

Tags: jquery

I would like to simulate dropping stones into a bucket on the web.

Drag and drop plus simple gravity simulation comes to mind.

Is there an example, jQuery plugin, or something that makes this straight-forward and clean?

Thanks!

Comment: I ... don't think many of us understand what you want. Do you mean something like this: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/snowstorm/ (also note, I didn't vote yet)

Comment: good point. Things I had in mind were gravity, drag-and-drop, collision detection, and stacking the stones on top of each other. I was about to write this in raw JavaScript and decided that the approach I was going to take was overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need graphic extensive animations, everything can be done quite easily with HTML and Javascript; absolute positioned elements and jQuery's `animate` function.

** **EDIT** **

Take a look [here](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~rcpinto/physics/). It seems to be exactly what you want.

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755852/acceleration-with-jquery).

Comment: Thank you. Although seeing code is nice, it's answers like these that I was looking for.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at creating something either Silverlight, ActionScript/Flash/Flex, or even more old school and go with a java applet.  Another thing you can check out is HTML5 canvas.

Comment: WOW WRONG! Javascript lets you do this straight out of the box, even on old skool HTML4 only implementations. See my link above in the comments for something similar, but for "snow".

Comment: This question amounts to "point me to a web page that shows me a well-written, complete example of a simulation that suits my fancy." It's "plz email me the codez" with better sentence structure.  It's probably a fun and interesting topic, but it's not a good question.

Comment: @Chris Farmer No, in fact if you read the OP he states: Is there an example, jQuery plugin, or something that makes this straight-forward and clean?  That is, in fact, a question and not open ended.  He is asking for a very specific set of criteria.  He's not asking you to write his code, nor email him some code.  What he's asking for is prior precedence - something he can base his work on.  He's not asking for a fish, he's asking you to point him in the direction in learning how to fish.